# Invalid object name 'dbo.sp_GetCustomerRequestReport'. when executing the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetCustomerRequestReport] 
    @FromDate DATETIME, 
    @ToDate DATETIME, 
    @UserId INT, 
    @LoginUserId INT
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT
        SU.FullName AS FullName,
        FORMAT(CAST(@FromDate AS DATE), 'dd-MM-yyyy') AS FromDate,
        FORMAT(CAST(@ToDate AS DATE), 'dd-MM-yyyy') AS ToDate 
    FROM
        SecUsers SU 
    WHERE
        SU.UserId = @LoginUserId 
END
```

When executing the above procedure, SQL Server shows an error

> Invalid object name

Please provide me statement of executing the above stored procedure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you getting the error running the Sql? If so, then The error means , You can't ALTER an object that doesn't exist. Change alter to CREATE

Comment: Are you trying to create a new stored procedure, change an existing proc, or execute an existing one? The script in your question is attempting to change one but it does not exist. Also, do not begin stored procedure names with `sp_` since that is used for system procs.

Comment: either the procedure does not exist at all, or it does not exist in the specified database or schema.

Comment: creation for store procedure is now done but for alter what to do?

Comment: If your create script is the same as your alter script then you don't need to run the alter script , if it's not then run the alter script otherwise I don't know what you mean.

Comment: after creation store procedure folder didn't add GetCustomerRequestReport yet. And as I'm at beginner level so for learning I want to know how to execute Alter Statement.

Comment: An alter procedure is just a query , execute it in whatever interface you have.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure of the following:

- You are currently connected to the database that has the SP to alter.
- The SP exists (has already been created) and it's on the dbo schema (since you are trying to alter it there).
- The user that is running the statement has enough privileges to modify it.
- Check if the "invalid object name" message does not refer to the table being used on the SP definition.

If you can't find it on the object explorer means that either it hasn't been created, you haven't been granted permission to see it or you are looking in the wrong server, database or schema.
Try executing the same script but with CREATE instead of ALTER, if it already exists then it should fail.